# CSS table cell fill remaining space in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I got a table which takes full body height & width because it's an absolute layout which will mostly be seen inside a popup so I don't have fixed size for it. My table has 4 rows: `header, body, footer`. Header & footer have a fixed size while the `body` part is flexible meaning that it stretches to fill whatever space remains in the table.

It works fine in chrome where I usually develop but fails miserably in firefox. Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdFSh/5/

Yes, I need that `#absolute` div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added height: 100% to all tr elements on your table (right before your tr#top rule) and it fixed the issue on firefox.
Like so:

```
table tr { height: 100%; }
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdFSh/6/

Comment: works perfect. Is this something known about firefox or tables in general?